# Feed list of candles as variable to backtrader

Tags: python, backtrader

I hаvе list of `Candle` objeсts and want to feed them straight to сerebro without saving to csv and loading from csv, but can't figure out how to do it.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dataclasses import dataclass

import backtrader as bt


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Candle:
    open: float
    high: float
    low: float
    close: float
    volume: int
    time: datetime
    is_complete: bool | None = None


class TestStrategy(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dataclose = self.datas[0].close

    def next(self):
        print(self.dataclose[0])


def main():
    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
    cerebro.broker.set_cash(100_000)
    cerebro.broker.setcommission(0.03)
    
    candles = [Candle(open=i, high=i+2, low=i-2, close=i, volume=i*100, time=datetime.utcnow()) for i in range(1, 101)]
    data = bt.DataBase(candles)
    cerebro.adddata(data)
    cerebro.addstrategy(TestStrategy)

    print(f'Starting Portfolio Value: {cerebro.broker.get_value()}')
    cerebro.run()
    print(f'Final Portfolio Value: {cerebro.broker.get_value()}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output without any price print:

```
Starting Portfolio Value: 100000 

Final Portfolio Value: 100000`
```

I saw something about [extending data feed](https://www.backtrader.com/docu/extending-a-datafeed/), but didn't understand how to manage it for my case. Tried init `LineSeries`, but got error while adding data. Is it possible to feed data from variable to `backtrader` module?